# Ports not getting free (nodemon)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, nodemon

im using nodemon to reload my server, but when i save the file it throws me a error,
it says that the port is alredy being used by another process.

this is the error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1280:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1415:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/yamil/code/tasksApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yamil/code/tasksApp/index.js:23:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1307:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

pd: im using Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Can you run `netstat -plnt` on the command line and show the line with port 3000? It will look like `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000 ....`

Comment: i just run the command, this is the output:  ```tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      47098/node```

Comment: now run `kill -9 47098` and you should be good.

Comment: yeah, it kills the process, but when i run nodemon and i save it stills showing the same error

Comment: @YamilYscapa I am facing the same issue, something goes wrong when I save the file and application get re-builds. After killing the process it starts runs correctly and then entire thing repeat itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to kill all programs listening on the port:

```
lsof -ti tcp:3000 | xargs kill
```